# Install Azure.Identity and all dependent packages to the gac

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, global-assembly-cache

I was able to download the Azure.Identity and its dependancies to a folder on my machine after looking at this article -  [Force download of specific nuget package to local packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769792/force-download-of-specific-nuget-package-to-local-packages-folder) using the following command: `nuget.exe install "Azure.Identity" -source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" -OutputDirectory "C:\My\Folder"` The intent is to use this for SSIS .net framework 4.8 so not sure if I needed to do anything different here. I then ran `gacutil.exe /i C:\My\Folder\Azure.Identity.1.10.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Azure.Identity.dll` and it installed successfully and i was able to see the dll in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` and was able to add the reference to my ssis script task. I would like to do this with all of the dependancies as well.

Is there a faster way of doing this instead of loading one assembly into the GAC at a time? There are 17 individual folders will all of the dependent assemblies. If this works on my machine I will need to hand it over to the admins to install it on our servers and I am sure there is going to be some push back if they have to do each assembly individually for all of our servers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at the command line options for gacutil.exe `gacutil.exe /?` I don't see anything that screams out to me "install everything in this location" You could try an approach like  `dir /s /b C:\My\Folder\*.dll > C:\My\GacThis.txt` and the use that file to drive your gacutil calls.